# Why am I am getting null entry for parameter 'CarLotID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'ActionResult DisplaySearchResults()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am creating an MVC application and I am trying to display data on my table based on the selected values for multiple dropdowns once a button is clicked. I think I am assigning all the values in my code but I am new to coding so I am not sure if I am missing something.

This is my view

```
@model IgnitionHub2._0.Models.Car
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Car Search Page";
}

<h2>Cars</h2>
<div class="center-div">
    <div class="form-inline">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarLotID, new SelectList(Model.CarLotList, "CarLotID", "LotName"), "Select Car Lot", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Model.MakeID, new SelectList(Model.MakeList, "MakeID", "Name"), "Select Make", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ModelID, new SelectList(Model.ModelList, "ModelID", "Name"), "Select Model", new { @class = "form-control" })
        <button id="search">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="searchResults">

</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function () {
    var makeUrl = '@Url.Action("GetCarDetails")';
    var models = $('#ModelID')
    $('#Model_MakeID').change(function () {
        models.empty();
            $.getJSON(makeUrl, { MakeID: $(this).val() },function(data){
                if (!data) {
                    return;
                }
                models.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    models.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Name));
                });
            });
        })
    })
    $(document).ready(function () {
     var url = '@Url.Action("DisplaySearchResults","Car")';
    $('#search').click(function () {
        var carLotID = $('#CarLotID').val();
        var makeID = $('#Model_MakeID').val();
        var modelID = $('#ModelID').val();
        alert(modelID);
        $('#searchResults').load(url, { CarLotID: carLotID, MakeID: makeID, ModelID: modelID });
    })

    })
```

This is my Partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<IgnitionHub2._0.Models.Car>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Color)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mileage)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BodyType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Drive)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Available)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarLot.LotName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Color)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mileage)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BodyType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Drive)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Available)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CarLot.LotName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CarID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CarID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CarID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

And this is my controller

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var cars = db.Cars.Include(c => c.Model).Include(c => c.CarLot);
        var makeList = db.Makes.ToList();
        var modelList = db.Models.ToList();
        var carLotList = db.CarLots.ToList();
        var ViewModel = new Car
        {
        CarList = cars,
        MakeList = makeList,
        ModelList= modelList,
        CarLotList = carLotList
        };

        return View(ViewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults(int CarLotID, int MakeID, int ModelID)
    {
        var model = db.Cars.Where(c => c.Model.MakeID == MakeID && c.ModelID == ModelID &&
        c.CarLotID == CarLotID).ToList();// build list based on parameter searchText
        return PartialView("_Index", model);
    }
    public ActionResult _Index()
    {
        var cars = new List<Car>(); 
        return PartialView(cars);
    }
    public JsonResult GetCarDetails(int MakeID)
    {

        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var data = GetModels(MakeID).ToList();
        //data = data.Where(x => x.Model.MakeID == MakeID).ToList();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Please Help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where are you getting that error. Can you point to the line that is getting the exception in your code?

Comment: @gilliduck the error happens when I click on the submit button, not sure which line is causing the issue because the program doesn't crash, it just doesn't display the table or any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, https://api.jquery.com/load/, `.load()` uses POST http request **if you're passing an object as parameter, which you are doing right now with;**

```
// {CarLotID:carLotID,MakeID:makeID,ModelID:modelID} is an object
$('#searchResults').load(url, { CarLotID: carLotID, MakeID: makeID, ModelID: modelID });
```

OPTION 1-- Since you didn't write your action method to be POST, you could just configure your `.load()` to use GET.

**Use the code below for** `.load()`;

```
$('#searchResults').load(url+"?CarLotID="+carLotID+"&MakeID="+makeID+"&ModelID="+modelID);
```

then change

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ModelID, new SelectList(Model.ModelList, "ModelID", "Name"), "Select Model", new { @id="ModelID", @class = "form-control" })`

In your loop to refill the dropdown, use this instead;

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
         models.append($('<option value="+item.MakeID+"></option>').text(item.Name));
});
```

updated script:

```
$('#Model_MakeID').change(function(){
   models.empty();
   $.getJSON(makeUrl, { MakeID: $(this).val() }, function(data){
      if (!data) {
         return;
      }
      models.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));

      // update this
      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
         models.append($('<option value="+item.Value+"></option>').text(item.Name));
      });
   });
});
```

---

OR OPTION 2-- just add `[HttpPOST]` attribute to your controller action.

```
[HttpPost] // add this
public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults(int CarLotID, int MakeID, int ModelID)
{
        ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried both ways and was unsuccessful. With option 1 I get the error ModelID is null even when I am selecting a modelID. With option 2 I get error http 404 The resource cannot be found.

Comment: @SmileyRod will you debug your javascript or just add `alert(modelID)` just to see if you're really getting its value?

Comment: Then try changing the parameter to string `public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults(int CarLotID, int MakeID, string ModelID)`

Comment: I added alert(modelID) and I had a pop up say "localhost:1234 says "

Comment: I tried changing the parameter to `public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults(int CarLotID, int MakeID, string ModelID)` but I had an error saying cannot convert int to string on ModeilID

Comment: @SmileyRod in your view, try changing the ModelID dropdown to `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ModelID, new SelectList(Model.ModelList, "ModelID", "Name"), "Select Model", new { @id="ModelID", @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: @SmileyRod Also rightclick > inspect element the dropdown and check if the option fields have the correct value attribute

Comment: I was able to do that and I realized that I added a script to change the model based on the selected make and once the make is selected, this refreshes the values of my model dropdown and I believe this is why I send a null value. I edited the view on my post now to show the other script since I cant add it to the comment.
Before selecting a make `<option value="1">Civic</option>`
After selecting the make `<option value="">Civic</option>`

Comment: @SmileyRod I updated the answer. In your script that refills the dropdown, do this instead; `models.append($('<option value="+item.Value+"></option>').text(item.Name));`

Comment: I was able to add the code but now when I select the dropdown I get the following: `<option value="+item.Value+">Civic</option>` Btw, thank you so much for helping me with this.

Comment: Oops sorry, please replace it with single quote. Here's the updated line of code; `models.append($('<option value='+item.Value+'></option>').text(item.Name));`

Comment: With that code I get <option value="undefined">Civic</option>

Comment: @SmileyRod will you include the controller action that gives that json result?

Comment: I edited  the post to include that controller. I apologize for not including this code in the original post.

Comment: @SmileyRod That's fine, one more thing; `var data = GetModels(MakeID).ToList();` will you add a breakpoint there and see what's the list and the properties of that list being returned? thanks

Comment: I added a breakpoint there and I got data as null and makeID 1. When I expand on data I see _empty array. this is the GetModels 
 `private List<Model> GetModels(int MakeID)
        {
            return db.Models.Where(q => q.MakeID == MakeID).ToList();
        }`
Only things on this table in my database are MakeID and Name

Comment: @SmileyRod I updated the answer, update your get request url to `$.getJSON(makeUrl+"MakeID="+makeID,function(data){
      // ... the rest of your code here
   });`

Comment: With this update my model dropdown goes completely empty

Comment: @SmileyRod Okay revert it back. I'm confused m you mentioned you only have MakeID and Name, you should use that instead of Value. `models.append($('<option value="+item.MakeID+"></option>').text(item.Name));`

Comment: Use this `models.append($('<option value="+item.MakeID+"></option>').text(item.Name));`

Comment: Im sorry if that was confusing, Im not the greatest at explaining things sometimes. i tried this code and it gave all my ModelID the values of my MakeID so I changed the code you gave me to `models.append($('<option value='+item.ModelID+'></option>').text(item.Name));` Same code you gave me I just changed MakeID to ModelID and this made it work!!! Thank you so much for working on this issues with me and being so patient! Again Thank you so much for guiding me through this.

Comment: @SmileyRod Nice it worked! you're welcome, good luck with the project :D